# Proyecto Laravel error DOM

Tags: laravel, apache, php8, rhel

Cuando intento inicializar un proyecto en una VM con RHEL 8, me arroja el siguiente error:

```
 Error 

  Class "DOMDocument" not found

  at vendor/nunomaduro/termwind/src/HtmlRenderer.php:32
     28▕      * Parses the given html.
     29▕      */
     30▕     public function parse(string $html): Components\Element
     31▕     {
  ➜  32▕         $dom = new DOMDocument();
     33▕ 
     34▕         if (strip_tags($html) === $html) {
     35▕             return Termwind::span($html);
     36▕         }

      +9 vendor frames 
  10  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Los comandos php /usr/local/bin/composer update y php /usr/local/bin/composer install, el siguiente:

```
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles is locked to version 2.2.6 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.6 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/pint is locked to version v1.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/pint v1.4.0 requires ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension.
  Problem 3
    - phar-io/manifest is locked to version 2.0.3 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phar-io/manifest 2.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 4
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage is locked to version 9.2.23 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 9.2.23 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 5
    - phpunit/phpunit is locked to version 9.5.28 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - phpunit/phpunit 9.5.28 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 6
    - theseer/tokenizer is locked to version 1.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - theseer/tokenizer 1.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 7
    - tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles 2.2.6 requires ext-dom * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
    - laravel/framework v9.48.0 requires tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles ^2.2.5 -> satisfiable by tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles[2.2.6].
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v9.48.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-dom --ignore-platform-req=ext-xml` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/pint[v1.0.0, ..., v1.6.0] require ext-xml * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xml extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/pint ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/pint[v1.0.0, ..., v1.6.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
```

Tengo la version de PHP 8.1 instalada, pero sin embargo, Apache me reconoce la 7.2:

Comando php -v

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la imagen de apache:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el error puede venir por acá, ya que tuve bastantes inconvenientes al querer instalar PHP 8.1, pero una vez logrado, no pude hacer que Apache me lo reconozca, busqué por varios foros, varias preguntas acá, en internet y en ninguna puedo dar con la solución, realmente no sé que es lo que está fallando y no puedo avanzar.

¿Alguien que pueda guiarme un poco en que está pasando? Cualquier información extra que necesiten la puedo brindar.

Gracias